# Memory Management Autorelease vs. Alloc Question

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory

3 correlated questions:

1.Do the code snippets below provide the very same results in terms of memory?

```
NSBundle *bundle=[[NSBundle alloc] init];
[bundle release];
bundle=nil;
```

and

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
[pool drain];
pool=nil;
bundle=nil;
```

2.Why in

```
NSBundle *bundle=[[NSBundle alloc] init];
[bundle release];
```

the retainCount of bundle is 1, not 0?

3.Which is recommended: always use class methods, or always gain ownership by using alloc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, those should be equivalent in terms of memory management, from the developer's point of view.  The frameworks might be doing something behind the scene to hang on to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, but that's not your concern.
2. Ignore `retainCount`.  *waves hand* That's not the method you're looking for.  Once you have relinquished ownership of an object, either by invoking `release` or `autorelease`, then it is invalid (bad practice) to send more messages to that object.  In your example, you `alloc` an `NSBundle`, so you own it.  That means it has a +1 retain count (I say +1, because it's relative).  When you release the bundle, it now has a "0" retain count, which means you no longer own this object (despite whether or not it may still exist in memory), which means you should *not* send messages to it, under penalty of stuff blowing up in your face.
3. What's recommended is to use whatever's appropriate for the situation.  If you just need a temporary object, then using a class method that returns an autoreleased object is probably going to be just fine.  If you need to be absolutely sure that the object isn't going to go away while you're using it, then you can use an `alloc`/`init` approach (or `retain` an autoreleased object) and then just `release` it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the second example you will create 1 extra object (the NSAutorealeasePool) and because of that the two are not *exactly* the same in terms of memory. But after the code runs I believe the memory will return to the same state in both examples. I am not really sure but I believe that in the second example `bundle` is an autoreleased object, so when the pool is drained it gets released.
2. I believe that when the object gets dealloc'ed the retainCount isn't changed.
3. It is usually recommended to avoid class methods when you create a lot of temporary objects because they won't get released until the next AutoreleasePool drain is called (and if you don't have an AutoreleasePool inside your method it won't happen for sure until you return from your method - and maybe even later). Otherwise you should use the one that feels better for you. I personally prefer allocating them. It is also important to remember that if you want the autoreleased object (the one returned from a class method) to stick around even after you return from the function to retain it.